# how can someone view fuel shortage alerts?

Tags: airport, usa, fuel

Quoting https://www.kvue.com/article/news/local/new-jet-fuel-tanks-at-austin-airport-will-be-built-as-planned-after-split-council-vote/269-d7490d00-01f7-4330-9026-71f619f7ad8b ,

> Airport leaders have issued 16 fuel shortage alerts since 2019, 11 of them last year. The alert is triggered when the current fuel supply drops below one day’s worth.

My question is...  how can one see fuel shortage alerts?

Would this be through a NOTAM or would you have to tune your radio to the CTAF frequency or whatever?

Comment: I think you may be caught by their use of the term "issued."  It implies there's some sort of broadcast or notification to the FAA.  I suspect this isn't the case at all, and by "issued" what they mean is the fuel supplier sent an email out to those with larger commercial accounts.  That might include a larger FBO, a charter operation, a regional airline contact...  But I suspect it's unlikely something a local or transient pilot will know without making a phone call to check on fuel status.  It would definitely not be a NOTAM, nor broadcast on a radio frequency.

Comment: @Max - I think in general you’re right. But I think it’s probably airport management that sends the email, not the fuel suppliers. And then, to whom do they send it?  Maybe the fuel suppliers to say, “Hey we need more fuel *now* and maybe to the airlines to say, “Be aware we might not have fuel for you when you get here”.

Comment: @Jim That hasn't been my experience.  Yes, on a small field in a small town, the airport manager might be the person who does everything, including managing fuel levels and calling for refills.  But in a typical mid-sized field the fuel vendor is just a tenant.  It would be much like a shopping mall manager monitoring the juice levels at Orange Julius, they're just not involved.  I don't buy my avgas from the airport, I buy it from the vendor, who has systems that forecast demand and electronically monitor fuel usage at the pumps.

Comment: @Max - you’re probably right, but I also think I’m thinking of “fuel suppliers” differently than you are. To me, fuel suppliers are the people that bring the fuel to the airport not the people who sell it there. It’s not Orange Julius it’s Sysco.